# Run outputType library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library

I have an ASP.NET project with outputType library, I need to run the project but it's not running. what outputType should i use to make my project run?

Comment: A Library ASP.NET will output a dll
So nothing runnable just a flat dll.
If you wanna test it, create a new Project Console or Window call the library.

Comment: @PedroFerreira I want run it as web project, when i run the project it is tell me "the project with output library tape cannot be run"

Comment: Check the answer of @"huMpty duMpty" to see if its not simply a lack of set startUp Project.

If thats not the issue, well then you've selected the wrong type of projects. 
Recreate your ASP:NET Web Application Solution and post in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In order to fix the above error, right click the Solution name in Visual 
Studio 2005/2008 and select Set as StartUp Project option from the popup menu.
```

source : [Fix: A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly](http://www.learnxpress.com/fix-a-project-with-an-output-type-of-class-library-cannot-be-started-directly.html)

Answer (score 1):

Despite `ASP.NET` projects have `Class Library` type, Visual Studio can "run" these types of projects(it deploys project's output to IIS or dev server and starts web-app).

So to solve your problem you should tell Visual Studio somehow that your project is ASP.NET project.  I see to ways:

*1-st one - fast, straighforward, dumb, but **reliable***: create new "ASP.NET Web Application" project in visual studio and copy all sources to it.

*2-nd - not sure that it's working, but more hack'ier and fun*:  open YourProject.csproj file in text editor, replace `<ProjectTypeGuids ...>` section by such ones, that could be found in csproj file of ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 0):

Class library projects can not be run, you can debug them though. See [Debugging DLL Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164704.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A project with an output type of class Library cannot be started directly.In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.Means
`In VS.Net - right click on the page you want to be the initial startup page and set it to be the startup page.`